# My CSS, and JS Organization is not working

Tags: css

I have trouble to make my Css and Javascript working. Here is a capture of my current work. I have created a folder with my different html pages and same for Css and js (i only have one css for everything and several js).

It worked when all my htmls, Css and Js are into the main folder but when it comes to organize into severel foldes, nothing is working except my Htmls.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6GRS.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you include your project folder structure and your code as formatted text (instead of an image)?

Comment: You should post the actual code here, a screenshot is generally unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

All your files are in different directories and if you have to link your HTMLs with the CSS and JS files, you have to get out of the HTMLs directory to the parent directory. And, then specify the path to the CSS, JS, and Images.

Use this to reach the parent directory of the current directory.

```
../
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Visual Studio Code, there is a trick for call CSS and Javascript

```
@Styles.Render("~/css/style.css")
@Styles.Render("~/css/yourstyle.css")
```

and is a good practice to separate css from javascript folder

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/yourscript.js")
```